# buttons stuck on top of page

Tags: javascript, css

I am creating a hangman game for a school project. Hangman obviously has 26 buttons on the page, with (ideally) the hyphen word on top. We are also required to make all 26 buttons using one for loop rather than 26 button tags. My issue is moving the buttons to the middle of the page (the buttons are defaulted to the top), as all the methods I've tried are not working. I need help to move my buttons to the bottom of the page.

I've tried giving all my buttons a class and doing [position:absolute;, bottom: 0;]. The issue with this method was that the button[s] were moved the bottom, but only the z button was visible. I believe, since I used a for loop, each button was over written by the next one while stopping at z.

```
/* my button creating function */
document.getElementById("letters")
for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
   var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
   var letterString = String.fromCharCode(97 + i);
   button.id = letterString;
   button.classList.add("letterButton")
   var tee = document.createTextNode(letterString);
   button.appendChild(tee);
   button.addEventListener("click", buttonHandler);
   document.body.appendChild(button);
}

/* my css that supposedly should move the buttons */
.letterButton { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Expected all buttons to be moved to the bottom of the page and visible. Actual results was that only one button [z] was moved to the bottom of the page and visible.

Comment: 1) line four within the for loop: button.classList.add("letterButton")

Comment: For question 2, I am not sure of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could append the individual buttons to a container `<div>` instead of the DOM and ultimately move that `<div>` to the bottom.

```js
var container = document.createElement("div");
container.id = "container";
container.classList.add("container")
document.body.appendChild(container);

function buttonHandler()
{
}

for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
  var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var letterString = String.fromCharCode(97 + i);
  button.id = letterString;
  var tee = document.createTextNode(letterString);
  button.appendChild(tee);
  button.addEventListener("click", buttonHandler);
  container.appendChild(button);
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: the code did fulfill the requirement of getting the code to the bottom of the page. However, in order to appeal to having as little code in the problem for the sake of efficiency, I left out all the other css I used in my buttons. Some of the css includes [height, width, font, colour, border-radius and much more]. The issue with the code you've provided, is that for some reason all the other css gets completely messed up. The font no longer works, the sizes are random, random white circle in the back, and more. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Uhm I'm not too sure. I left out the following line of your script because it wasn't needed for my example: `button.classList.add("letterButton");` So maybe your buttons are just missing it's css styles. (just keep in mind that the position property of those should be: relative)

Comment: Yeah I fixed the code to add that attribute! I completely blanked out and forgot about it. I appreciate the help, and everything is back to normal now!